# Elasticsearch date range query over text field

Tags: python, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-query

I have 2 date fields in my documents say `date_field_1` and `date_field_2`. All documents has `date_feild_1` data, but for `date_filed_2` few of them have empty string. Because of this `date_field_1` is marked as date field and `date_field_2` is marked as text field.

Now when I try executing the query,

```
{"range": {"date_field_1": {"gte": "2022-05-23", "lte": "2022-05-23"}}}
```

I am getting proper results. But when I try the same for `date_field_2` I am getting empty result.
Is there a way to apply range query to `date_field_2` over non empty documents?

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex eventually:

```
{
    "range": {
        "date_field_2": "2022-0[3-6]-[0-9][0-9]"
    }
}
```

The above query will return anything in between `2022-03-01` and `2022-06-30`
Basically you request data that contain in `date_field_2` a value that contain `2022-0` then any number in `3-6` range, then a `-` and any 2 numbers in `0-9` range
Please be aware that it will also return wrong values, IF THEY EXISTS (like `2022-03-87`) but that's a different story

Comment: Not working. Dates are dynamic. Though regex wont work if I want to filter it from 2022-05-20 to 2022-06-15

Comment: what dynamically means?

Comment: Its from the user end.Have no control

Comment: you mean the format (ex yyyy-mm-dd) is dynamic?